# Listing the applications running in Android using a program not with any software

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Android programming. I am trying to display all the currently running applications in the emulator. Is it possible? I am writing it using Eclipse Linux platform. I installed Android SDK and was able to successfully run basic programs. My Android platform is Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, you want to see the running processes on the emulator :

In the emulator, there is a 'DevTools' application.
Launch it, click 'development Settings', and click 'Show Running Process'

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying. But i want the current applications only not the processes. Processes can be many right. Ofcours, running application is also a process but i need only the running applications?

Comment: I have a doubt, In linux we can capture the output of any file into a file right. Is there any way to take the output of an .apk file and copy it into a file. Plz help me out friend.

Comment: what do you mean copy the "output" of an .apk file..?